# Display 3 images in a row using php

Tags: php, html, image

I want to show 3 images in a row but i cant find the problem in my code.

```
<div class="pagh">


<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from imagens INNER JOIN users ON imagens.id_user = users.id_user ";
$consulta = mysqli_query($bd, $sql);
$n_linhas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
if ($n_linhas!=0) {
    for ($i=1;$i<=$n_linhas;$i++){
        $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="column">
                   <img src="user_img/' . $dados["filename"] . '" width="150%">';

        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }//for
}//if
?>
```

[code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2ux0.png)

Comment: Share some code

Comment: I can't find your code ;)

Comment: Laugh Out Loud.

Comment: Code _in_ the question please and as _text_ not an image of text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change your code like this :

```
echo '<div class="row">;
for($i = 1; $i<$n_linhas;$i++){
    echo '<div class="column">
             <img src="...">
          </div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

In your code, at each $i your write a new row
Inspect your code with right click to see what happend

Comment: you're right that the row dive needs to be outside the loop, but this won't solve the problem.  This loop you have suggested will run on until the array is finished, which could be who knows how long.  You need a break out at some point, also $dados["filename"] cannot be valid as this is an array of results, so we need to access the array